# Resizing a div to fit content with maximum height

Tags: jquery, css, html, resize

I have a div with dynamic content. When the content loads in the div I want the div to resize to fit the content. But I want this resizing to have a maximum height. If the content needs more than this maximum height I'd like there to be a scrollbar.

I've searched through the questions here but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for (apart from one where the question-asker replied saying he'd figured it out himself). I've read I can do it with jquery but I'm pretty new to that, but I did go through the demos of resizing a div, and changing classes and stuff like that but I'm really at a loss on how to implement what I'm looking for. I *have* tried to find a solution to this, so please be gentle.

Comment: Hopefully you don't have to worry about this, but IE 6 doesn't support the max-height attribute. Just something to keep in the back of your mind

Comment: Hurm, is there a way round the max-height in IE6?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
 div {height:auto;overflow:scroll;max-height:200px;}
```

Comment: Downvoting, because even perfectly correct, but still pure-code answers, without even tiny text of explanation, are so wrong.

Comment: This doesn't work when the height is larger than your defined max-height.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<div style="max-height: 400px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x: hidden">
<p>Some dynamic content loads inside the div</p>
</div>
```

Then add: `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before closing the "div":

```
<div style="max-height: 400px">
<p>Some dynamic content loads inside the div</p>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with css, e.g.: `max-height: 100px; overflow-y:scroll;`