# FullCalendar auto-height in week view

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to have a calendar in week mode which would take all the width it can take and take all the height it needs to not have scrollbars.

If I keep default settings `height: auto, aspectRation: 1.35`, I see a vertical scrollbar:
[image]

If I change `aspectRatio` to 1, scrollbar disappears but I see a useless empty area at the bottom:

[image]

Is there any way to fix it except guessing the aspectRatio (which is not a case for me as minTime and maxTime are dynamically changed so the conent height changes)?

Comment: You could try changing the css maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398069/resizing-a-div-to-fit-content-with-maximum-height

Comment: What version of fullcalendar are you using?

Comment: @MarCrazyness, FullCalendar v2.1.1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Edit:**

Fullcalendar v2.1.1

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/560/

```
contentHeight: 'auto',
```

**Solution for old versions?**

Kind of hack:ish. Does this work in your environment? I used the code from your other question.

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/558/

```
contentHeight: '9999',
```

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately it doesn't work for v2.1.1. Here you jsfiddle with updated External Resources: http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/559/

Comment: @Idsa thanks, I didn't realize. I found a solution that was less hack:ish too for the new fullcalendar version :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's confusing that it is not a default option. I should've payed more attention to documentation...

Comment: I agree, should be default

Comment: Seems like 'auto' option appeared recently (v. 2.1.0). So I guess it is not default due to backwards compatibility

Answer (score 12):

Adjusting dynamically the **height** instead of the **aspect ratio** worked for me:

Asigning the calendar to a variable when initiating:

```js
calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: $(window).height()*0.83,
    ...
});
```

And then adjusting height dynamically (after checking that calendar exists already in order to avoid initial error messages):

```js
if(calendar) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var calHeight = $(window).height()*0.83;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', calHeight);
  });
};
```

The factor `*0.83` depends on your page-design.

Hope this helps.
[image: Adam Shaw's fullcalendar at 100% height and scrollbars]

[image: Day view, spanish (as fullcalendar is multilingual - lol]

Answer (score 0):

For version 3 and 4 you can try add `height: 'parent'` to your config.
ref: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/height

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting the height to auto would work: It works in Month view for me.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            timezone: 'local',
            ignoreTimezone: true,
            defaultView: 'month',
            weekNumbers: false,
            slotDuration: "00:15",
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotEventOverlap: false,
            firstDay: '1',
            height:'auto',
```