# fullcalendar - Adjust height to fit minTime/maxTime

Tags: fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar.io, when I restrict the displayed times on an agenda, the calendar still draws the same size (based on the aspect ratio), however most of this is now wasted space.

Is there a way to adjust the height to the height of the agenda times? (Keeping in mind that the user may switch to another view such as a full month and need the larger height.)

http://jsfiddle.net/yz82qepq/1/

```
calendar = jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agenda',
    minTime: '08:00:00',
    maxTime: '12:00:00'
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FullCalendar auto-height in week view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329377/fullcalendar-auto-height-in-week-view)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, realized this is a duplicate of [FullCalendar auto-height in week view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329377/fullcalendar-auto-height-in-week-view)

Solution: "contentHeight: 'auto',"