# FullCalendar, day view: fit height to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar, fullcalendar

The question is about FullCalendar v3.4.0.

If you open the example [here](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/demos/agenda-views.html) and choose day view, you get a vertical scrollbar. I want the view to fit to the browser window instead. What I mean is that I want the height to shrink when the browser window height shrinks, and have no scrollbar.

I haven't found a way to achieve this. Also, I found the following CSS code, which might be relevant:

```
/* TimeGrid Slats (lines that run horizontally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
    height: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: 0; /* each cell is responsible for its top border */
}
```

Looks like the `height` of each cell is fixed, but I'm not skilled enough to say.

I prefer not to modify the library source code, but that's an option as a last resort.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329377/fullcalendar-auto-height-in-week-view

Comment: @taha that solution is for v2, I'm using v3, and the solution doesn't seem to work

Comment: A partial solution: add the following CSS style, and play with the numbers: `#calendar .fc-time-grid .fc-slats td { font-size: calc(-0.3em + 3.2vh); }`